# Firebase specific libraries for Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I recently upgraded Android Studio to 4.0. I had initially delayed the upgrade because there was a communication that the recent version is not compatible with Firebase and Kotlin. Now after the upgradation I had to reconnect android studio to Firebase and the dependencies were set up again. What I find is that the recent Firebase updates has specific libraries for Kotlin. For instance in Realtime Database we have implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:19.3.1' as against implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1' for Java.

However, the Firebase assistant in Android Studio implements the java versions of the library. Is this a bug? I am confused. Do I change manually to the Kotlin specific libraries?

Comment: The Firebase assistant is not a very robust piece of software.  I recommend managing your dependencies by hand.

Answer (score 0):

ktx librarys are extensions librarys that have kotlin syntax. Thats mostly it.

ktx has kotlin syntax and the normal ones have java syntax.

You can read more here. https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx

Comment: Thats what I thought. So that means the Android Studio Assistant needs to get this updated.